# Evaluating the integral $\int \frac{dx}{x^2 \sqrt{x^2 + 1}}$

Tags: calculus

Two different ways give two different results:

**1) Trigonometric Substitution**

$$\int \frac{dx}{x^2 \sqrt{x^2 + 1}} = \int \frac{\sec^2 u}{\tan^2 u \sqrt{\tan^2 u +1}}du$$

$$= \int \frac{\sec u}{\tan^2 u}du = \int \frac{\cos u}{\sin^2 u}du$$

$$= - \csc u + c = - \frac{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}{x} + c$$

**2) Partial fractions**

$$\int \frac{dx}{x^2 \sqrt{x^2 + 1}} = \int \frac{du}{(u^2 -1) \sqrt{u^2}}$$

$$= \int \frac{du}{u(u-1)(u+1)} = \int \frac{du}{u} + \int \frac{^{-1}/_2}{u-1}du + \int \frac{^{-1}/_2}{u+1}du$$

$$= \log |u| -\frac{1}{2} \log |u^2 -1| + c$$

$$\log \sqrt{x^2 + 1} - \log |x| + c = \log \frac{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}{x} + c$$

Comment: what change of variable did you do in 2)?

Comment: You can differentiate to check which of them is right. (Be sure to check both, since there's always the chance that each derivation has an error.)

Comment: @hjhjhj57 I took $u^2 = x^2 +1$

Comment: Aha. I found my mistake. In 2) $du \neq dx$. Should I delete the question?

Comment: I think you didn't take into account that $\frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2-1}}du = dx$. Anyway, as @Semiclassical pointed out you can always check your results by differentiating.